# DBeaver auto-completes table name with mixed case, but throws "relation does not exist error"

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

- DBeaver: Version 23.0.1.202303250535
- MacBook Pro/Apple M1 Max/macOS Ventura 13.2.1
- Postgres DB on Azure (postgres11 I believe)

With DB and schema dialed-in on DBeaver, I start writing a simple query like

```
SELECT * FROM D
```

I get a pop-up suggesting lots of possibilities, one of which is Dim_Date (with lots of info about that table). Double-clicking on Dim_Date in the list autocompletes the query to

```
select * from "Dim_Date" dd
```

Running that query, however, gives

> SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: relation "Dim_Date" does not exist
> Position: 15

It plainly *does* exist, else I couldn't have used auto-completion.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you run the queries from `psql`? Maybe log everything (test/dev **not** prod)?

Comment: @Vérace yeah I tried going down the psql route, but haven't been able to get it installed on my Mac so far. Not sure if you mean DBeaver error logs, but the stacktrace isn't informative.

Comment: No, server logs, nothing to do with DBeaver!

Comment: The error says it does not exist and I would believe that. Have you looked for the table in the [Database Navigator](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/wiki/Database-Navigator) for the database you are connected to?

Comment: So the DB and Table definitely existed, I could see detail down to columns and table sizes etc. BUT there was some significant changes in behaviour this morning without having done anything but reconnect the VPN--somehow that led me to find some kind of anomalies in permissions. I used different user details, and the query works fine now. Unfortunately this all appears to have been Azure auth vagaries. Apologies @Vérace and Adrian and Marmite -- thank you for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

From the *lots of info* provided check the `object ID` (`oid`)  and for troubleshooting use the below query

```
 select * from pg_class where oid =  <oid>;
```

Comment: That produces a single record that appears to confirm that (in this case) relname='Dim_Date'